# Why does this device_create() call not create a /dev/ entry?

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver, pci, pci-e

I'm porting platform driver code to a PCIe variant and I don't understand why I'm not getting a `/dev/` entry to show up.  The platform driver code that has been modified:

```
static dev_t first;
static struct class * class;
ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS(my);
static int __init my_pci_init(void)
{

    int ret;
    /* Create a class entry in sysfs */
    if ((class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "test_driver")) == NULL) {
        pr_err("Couldn't create 'struct class' structure.");
        ret = -ENODEV;
        goto exit;
    }
    class->dev_groups = my_groups;
    /* Create the /dev/ file system entry */
    /* return value ignored: there's a 'struct class' to 'struct device' mapping */
    if (device_create(class, NULL, first, NULL, KBUILD_MODNAME) == NULL) {
        pr_err("Couldn't create entry in '/dev/' file system.");
        ret = -ENODEV;
        goto exit;
    } else {
        pr_info("Created a /dev/ entry.");
    }

    if ((ret = pci_register_driver(&pci_driver)) < 0) {
        pr_err("Couldn't register pci driver.");
    }
 exit:
    if (ret < 0) {
        my_pci_exit();
        pr_err(" ret = %d", ret);
    }
    return ret;
}

module_init(my_pci_init);
```

If the module name is 'cz_tdm', I was hoping the above code would create an entry `/dev/cz_tdm`.  At least it did when I was compiling this as a platform driver.

The driver enumerates just fine, an output of `lspci` shows that the driver was loaded and perusing the `sysfs` shows that all my attributes in `/sys/devices/virtual/...` are where I'd expect them to be.

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops.

Because it's not supposed too.  An overzealous deletion of code ripped out this necessary element:

```
/* Add the char device to the system. */
cdev_init(&cdev, &fops);
if ((ret = cdev_add(&cdev, first, DEV_MINOR_NUMBER_COUNT)) < 0) {
    pr_err("Couldn't add device to system: %d", ret);
    ret = -ENODEV;
    goto exit;
}
```